# WCF An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: .net, wcf, exception

I am getting the above error when trying to request data across WCF 4 using netctp. The app has been quite happily working on both my dev machine and the remote Windows 2008 server returning requests for data from Entity Framework. The app still works fine on my dev machine but does not work on the remote windows server when I am requesting a new page I created which is returning a bit more data than all of my other pages.

Before posting this question I have followed all the usual routes of maxing out all my nettcp binding properties incase it was a throttling issue as shown below.

```
<binding name="NetTcpBinding_IProfileService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
    openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
    transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="10"
    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
      maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
  <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
      enabled="false" />
  <security mode="None">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
  </security>
</binding>
```

I have also enabled WCF Tracing on the Windows 2008 server and although I can see the ‘Socket Connection aborted’ activity it doesn’t give me any more details than that.

I am now completely puzzled as to what my issue is and ask if there is anybody out there who may be able to shed some light on the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled tracing on both sides (server and client)? You should see the source of the error in one of the tracefiles.

My guess are that you may have to increase some values of the [XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.xmldictionaryreaderquotas.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for that but as you can see I have set all my reader quotas to 2147483647 and still it happens. I will continue to look for an error message in the Trace Files and see if i can see something that gives me a clue.

Comment: Turns out that my tracing on the server side was not enabled. I then found out that I had incorrectly set up one of my endpoints. So will mark this answer as correct as it did prompt me to go and check my tracing configuration.